# PhoneGap 3.x/Windows Phone 8 - all plugins are undefined

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

We are in the process of moving our project away from the old version of PhoneGap. We were using (2.5.0) and now moving to the most recent, up-to-date PhoneGap (3.1).

The app is running well on Android and iOS but, whereas before it was working on Windows Phone 8, now it is not. I have tried debugging what the cause is, and 'deviceready' is fired, but all my plugins are undefined, despite them being listed when I do:

```
phonegap plugins ls
```

Yet I cannot work out for the life of me why. If it helps, the config.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mycompany.myapp" version="0.0.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="Battery">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Battery" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Camera" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="wp-package" value="DebugConsole" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="wp-package" value="Notification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="wp-package" value="File" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="wp-package" value="FileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="wp-package" value="InAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="wp-package" value="NetworkStatus" />
    </feature>
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>
        My app
    </description>
    <author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        My Company
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using phonegap 3.3 and find that the same issue too. undefined plugin

However I try install the plugin first, then run the "phonegap run android" to generate the project. the plugin is working fine. cordova_plugins.js is modified with the plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on cordova 3.3 windows phone 8 application.
The cordova plugins that i use are not accessible via navigator.plugins.pluginname.method.
Instead they work when calling cordova.exec directly and they are able to access the native functionality

Does anybody else have a problem with plugins in windows phone platform?

Answer (score 0):

JosephT is right. Also my device plugin was wrongly installed. "`cordova run android`" fixes it.

I have cordova 3.3.1-0.1.2 and I am developing for Android.

What I did:
new project with cordova 
add plugins with cordova
add platform with cordova
open project in Eclipse, start make the deployment to device by Eclipse
One plugin (not from cordova) was working, but still I got "device is not defined“, when I listed my plugins in CLI, device was installed, but somehow not working.

When used in CLI "cordova run android", probably Android platform part of project was re-created by CLI better than by Eclipse and device plugin start working.

**Attention!** When you will run "`cordova run android`" from CLI, *code which you created in Eclipse will be overwritten* by default from www folder in top of project. 
Make backup of project and try it, you will see what happen.